# is the closure of a totally convex set again totally convex?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, dg.differential-geometry

Recall that a totally convex subset $C$ of a complete Riemannian manifold $M$ is a set which contains with any two points $p,q$ also all the geodesics between them.

We know that there is a totally geodesic, totally convex submanifold $N\subset M$ such that $N\subset C \subset \bar N$. So the question is: Is $\bar N$ totally convex?

Comment: What about an open half sphere?

Comment: @Piero: an open half sphere is not totally convex. We want that all geodesics between points to be contained in the subset and not only the minimizing geodesics.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm dumb. How do you get $N$?

Comment: @Theo: consider $\cal N$ the family of all the submanifolds of $M$ contained in $C$. $\cal N$ is nonempty (e.g. points in $C$ are submanifolds of dimension 0).
And let $k$ be the maximal dimension of a submanifold in $\cal N$. Then $N$ is the union of all submanifolds in $\cal N$ of dimension $k$. The reference for this would be:

J. Cheeger and D. Gromoll, On the structure of complete manifolds
of nonnegative curvature.

Comment: The answer is definitely yes if $N$ has top dimension, i.e. $dim(N)=dim(M)$. Indeed, any geodesic outside $N$ that joins points of $\partial N$ can be extended to a geodesic joining points of $N$, and hence the geodesic must lie in $C$.  

Comment: @Igor: yes, that is true. I forgot to mention that the top dimensional case was not my problem. Although there is missing something in your argument. The geodesic $c$ joining points $p,q$ from the boundary of $C$ could be tangent to $C$, that is, the extension of this geodesic remains outside $C$. One has to approximate $p$ with points $p_i\in N$ and consider geodesics $c_i$ with initial vectors in $T_{p_i}N$ approximating the initial vector of $c$.

Comment: @carlos, yes, I was hasty. Now that I think of it, I do not even understand the top dimensional case. Would you edit the question to include the proof in  that case?

Comment: @Igor: sorry, I think I was not thorough enough in my consideration either. After looking at S. Ivanov's answer, I think that the answer for the top dimensional case is also "No". I think one could "thicken" $N$ in the example below given by S. Ivanov to a 2-dimensional set.

Comment: WARNING: I would like to point that the name *totally convex* may refer to several different definitions. The one carlos is using is the one given for example by Klingenberg (See def. 2.9.6 in his book _Riemannian Geometry_). However, M. Berger in his book _A Panoramic View of Riemannian Geometry (Springer, 2003)_ gives a different definition with the same name, where he only demands that all the *minimizing* geodesics will be in the set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Define a Riemannian metric tensor $g$ on $\mathbb R^2=\{(x,y)\}$ by
$$
 g(x,y) = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & f^2(x) \end{pmatrix}
$$
where $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is a positive smooth even function such that
$f(x) = \cos x$ for $|x|\le 1$ and $f''(x)/f(x)$ increases after $x=1$. Let $N$ be an open  segment of length $\pi$ in the $y$-axis, e.g. the one between points $A=(0,0)$ and $B=(0,\pi)$.

(The plane with this metric is isometric to the universal cover of a surface of revolution that looks like a unit sphere with two infinite tubes attached near a pair of opposite points. Note that the Gaussian curvature $K$ is given by $K=-f''/f$, so $K\le 1$ everywhere.)

The strip $\{|x|\le 1\}$ is isometric to the universal cover of a neighbourhood of the equator of the standard sphere, so there are plenty of geodesics between $A$ and $B$. On the other hand, using Clairot integral and the fact that the Gaussian curvature does not exceed 1, it is easy to see that no geodesic can intersect the $y$-axis at two points with distance less than $\pi$ between them. Hence $N$ is totally convex but its closure is not.

Comment: I'm sorry to ask. My intuition tells me it should be clear.
I really tried to get the computation but I didn't succeed. Could you give another hint in how to conclude that  no geodesic can intersect the $y$-axis at two points with distance less than $\pi$?

Comment: Suppose it does. Then the intersection points are not conjugate along the vertical segment, so you can vary it (as a geodesic) by varying the endpoints. Let the endpoints go to each other along this supposed second geodesic. The family of geodesics defined by these endpoints (started from the vertical segment) has decreasing length, because they form sharp angles with that second geodesic. Hence this family will be free of conjugate points for all time, and you'll get an arbitrarily short pair of distinct geodesics with the same endpoints, a contradiction.